# /etc/fstab pass enabled in filesystem, but with tune2fs -l "Last checked" not updated

Tags: filesystem, fstab

I already tried to look for this issue, but I do not find the explanation.

Why would a filesystem be marked with `<pass>=1, root filesystem`, or `<pass>=2` (in `/etc/fstab` file), i. e., `fsck` enabled at boot time seems not to update the parameter "Last checked". 
I mean "Last checked" the parameter you can show with `tune2fs` or `dumpe2fs`.

My Ubuntu is installed over a laptop, so I can assure you there are several boots per week.

Example of `/etc/fstab`, as you can see `fsck` is enabled at boot time.

```
/dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-root      /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=69e551b5-5167-4b50-9b89-f0a79afead43 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
```

Output of `tune2fs`/`dumpe2fs`:

```
# tune2fs -l 69e551b5-5167-4b50-9b89-f0a79afead43
Last mounted on:          /boot
Last mount time:          Wed Nov  9 17:12:18 2016
Last write time:          Wed Nov  9 17:12:18 2016
Last checked:             Sun Oct 23 20:46:24 2016

#tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-root
Last mounted on:          /
Last mount time:          Wed Nov  9 17:12:17 2016
Last write time:          Wed Nov  9 17:12:17 2016
Last checked:             Sun Jun 14 09:01:32 2015
```

Comment: From tune2fs what is mount count and check interval.